# Guards with multiple conditions/Nested guards

Tags: less

I am trying to make a mixin which evaluates both the parameters typ and compare values.

Say I have a mixin to create a CSS3 gradient with fallbacks for older browsers but if no start and/or end color is entered only output the background-color. In addition to checking all colors are being entered correctly I want to make sure that neither the start or end color is equal to the fallback color.

This is how I would like to write it using standard logic but I am not allowed to nest the guards together.

```
.gradient(@color, @start: 0, @stop: 0) when (iscolor(@color)) and (iscolor(@start)) and (iscolor(@stop)) and not ((@start = @color) and (@stop = @color)) {
    background: @color;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, @start),color-stop(1, @stop));
    additional-browser-specific-prefixes;
}

.gradient(@color, @start: 0, @stop: 0) when (default()) {
    background-color: @color;
}
```

Essentially I want to do the following Javascript condition: `if(iscolor(color) && iscolor(start) && iscolor(end) && (start !== color && end !== color))`. Does anyone have any clue if this is possible?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Less guards should have the same implementation as CSS @media (this maybe only apply for the syntax??). I can not find examples for the @media, which use the kind of nesting for operators you try to use. So it is not possible for CSS @media and so also not possible for Less guards?

But, on http://mdn.beonex.com/en/CSS/Media_queries.html i found:

> The not operator has a very low precedence.  For example, the not is
>   evaluated last in the following query:
>
> `@media not all and (-moz-windows-compositor) { ... }`
>
> This means that the query is evaluated like this:
>
> `@media not (all and (-moz-windows-compositor)) { ... }`
>
> ... rather than like this:
>
> `@media (not all) and (-moz-windows-compositor) { ... }`

This should mean that you do not have to wrap in extra parentheses your conditions after the `not` keyword. The following code should work:

<strike>`.gradient(@color, @start: 0, @stop: 0) when (iscolor(@color)) and (iscolor(@start) and not @start = @color) and (@stop = @color)`, but unfortunately this does not works as expected. 
If the operator precedence of Less guards have to equal to the operator precedence of the CSS @media, this could be considered as a bug maybe.</strike>

**update** My above assumption was wrong, the `not` keyword will be applied on the whole media query (or guard) only, so `not (a), not (b)` make no sense at all. Also see: https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2149

If all the above is truth, try to revert the conditions:

    <strike>.gradient(@color, @start: 0, @stop: 0) 
    when (@start = @color) and (@stop = @color), not (iscolor(@color)), not (iscolor(@start)), not (iscolor(@stop)) {
        background-color: @color;
    }</strike>

```
.gradient(@color, @start: 0, @stop: 0) 
when (@start = @color) and (@stop = @color), (iscolor(@color)=false), (iscolor(@start)=false), (iscolor(@stop)=false) {
    background-color: @color;
}

.gradient(@color, @start: 0, @stop: 0) when (default()) {
    background: @color;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, @start),color-stop(1, @stop));
    additional-browser-specific-prefixes;
}
```

or try to use nested mixins as follows:

```
default(@a,@b,@c){
property: default;
}
.fallback(@a,@b,@c){
property: fallback;
}

.background(@a,@b,@c) when (@a>0) and (@b>0) and (@c>0)
{
.and(@a,@b,@c) when (@a=@c) and (@b=@c) {
.fallback(@a,@b,@a);
}
.and(@a,@b,@c) when (default()){
.default(@a,@b,@a);
}
.and(@a,@b,@c);
}
.background(@a,@b,@c) when (default())
{
.fallback(@a,@b,@c);
}

test0 { .background(0,1,1); }
test1 { .background(1,1,1); }
test2 { .background(2,1,1); }
test3 { .background(1,2,1); }
test4 { .background(1,1,2); }
```

Comment: Thank you Bass for your comprehensive reply. The mixin with reverted guards does not work as expected, in the case of the start and stop color being the same as the fallback it will still render a positive result and print the gradient. There is a way to solve this using evaluated Javascript I guess but that is not only impractical but would also be bad practice in my opinion. I will however accept your answer as it is possible to nest the mixins to get the expected result, even if it is a somewhat tedious way of achieving it.

Comment: after some more testing, i see your are right and indeed the reverted guards will not work. Try to replace the `not (iscolor(@_))` with `(iscolor(@_)=false)`, than the reverted guards seem to work well. I made a wrong assumption about the `not`  keyword. `not @a, @b` should be evaluate as `not(@a,@b)` and not(@a),not(@b) does not make sense at all. From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries : "The not keyword applies to the whole media query ...."

Comment: Nice spot! We could open corresponding issue at the Less repo but I doubt the `not` priority will be changed (even if it conflicts with CSS spec.) - the main problem is that if `not a and b` is equal to `not (a and b)` then how will you write `not(a) and b`? Assuming that `when` use-cases vastly differ from `@media` use-cases even if the syntax itself pretends to be inherited I guess the better solution for the particular problem would be to allow nested `and`s and `not`s rather then changing `not`'s priority.